# How can I find which agent is currently active, i.e. it is displayed on the user's screen?

Tags: anylogic

How can I find which agent is currently active, i.e. it is **displayed on the user's screen**?

The fact is that my statistics are dynamically updated, including those related to accessing the Anylogic internal database. This update takes place every hour by event. Accordingly, if this screen is not active for the user, then I would not like to waste machine time updating this information.

Answer (score 0):

You should do it the other way around: Never update those stats *unless* a user looks at the agent.

You can do this by giving users a good UI to enter an agent:

- drag in a `ViewArea` into the agent type in question
- use the `navigateTo()` function in some UI button to let users navigate to specific agents
- combine that with a call to update whatever stats you want

Check the AnyLogic example models: Most make use of the technique of `ViewArea`s

PS: Its technically impossible to check if a user "looks" at an agent, afaik